# Apache is downloading .aspx page instead of displaying them

Tags: apache

Apache is downloading .aspx page instead of displaying them, Please let me know if someone has experienced same issue and got that fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not support ASP.NET by default.

Either switch to IIS (Internet Information Services) on Windows or install an Apache module that allows ASP.NET support.

For ASP.NET support in Apache check out http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply . but I'm using Apache as Reverse proxy server only , application is hosted on IIS.